# Handlebars возвращает пустую строку

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Искал в инете что может быть не так с моим кодом, но ничего не смог найти. Что именно я не так делаю? Может быть дело в том, что я неправильно передаю данные в `.hbs` файл?

Страница представляет из себя самый минимальный по своему устройству блог. Постишь заголовок и текст - вот оно и появилось на главной странице. Вот так выглядит модель типичной записи:

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose')

const schema = new Schema({
    title: { // ЗАГОЛОВОК
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    content: { // ТЕКСТ СТАТЬИ
        type: String,
        require: true
    }
})

module.exports = model('Article', schema)
```

Далее я хочу использовать эти данные на своих страницах и пишу в роутах следующее:

```
const { Router } = require('express')
const articles = require('../models/articles')
const router = Router()

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {data: articles}) // СЮДА КИДАЮ ДАННЫЕ
})

router.get('/post', (req, res) => {
    res.render('post', {isPost: true})
})

router.post('/post', async (req, res) => {
    const article = new articles({
        title: req.body.title,
        content: req.body.content
    })

    await article.save()
    res.redirect('/')
})

module.exports = router
```

Как видно выше, тут всего три роутов. Первый - это главная страница, куда я и кидаю записи из базы данных. Вторая просто формочка, куда я захожу, чтобы написать статейку. На переменную `IsPost` забейте, она нужен для кнопки в шапке, а там тоже всё слажено работает. Третий роут идёт после того, как мы подтверждаем данные и они закидываются в БД. Заглядываю в MongoDB и вижу, что всё хорошо. Данные реально сохраняются, форма работает, я доволен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь осталось вывести данные. Вот тут и начинается проблема. Вот таким образом я вывожу данные на страницу (она с Bootstrap, если что):

```
// ЗДЕСЬ ВАЖНЫЙ КУСОК КОДА
{{#if data.length}}
    <div style="max-width: 1240px" class="d-flex justify-content-center mx-auto">
        <div class="d-flex mt-5">
                <div class="d-flex row flex-wrap justify-content-center">
                    {{#each data}}
                        <div class="rounded border bg-light custom-item p-3 m-1">
                            <h4>{{this.title}}</h4>
                            <p class="text">{{this.content}}</p>
                        </div>
                    {{/each}}
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    // ЗДЕСЬ КОНЧАЕТСЯ ВАЖНЫЙ КУСОК КОДА

    <style>
        .custom-item{
            width: 240px;
            height: 240px;
        }

        .text{
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            display: -webkit-box;
            -webkit-line-clamp: 7;
                    line-clamp: 7; 
            -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        }
    </style>

{{else}}

    <div class="mt-5 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-column">
        <h1 class="text-black-50 text-center font-weight-bold">No articles</h1>
        <h4 class="text-muted text-center">Write your first post</h2>
    </div>
{{/if}}
```

Вместо того, чтобы вывести блоки с заголовками и их полным текстом, выводится это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратите внимание. Выводится только два блока с тегами `h4` и `p`, но они пустые. Выводится именно два блока, хотя в записей в базе данных всего три. Когда я меняю их количество, то блоков на странице по-прежнему всегда будет два.

И вот итоговый вопрос. Как работает мой код и почему он выводит именно два блока? Как мне исправить код так, чтобы вывести каждую запись из БД? Пишите, если забыл что-то ещё дополнить.

**UPD:** Код с роутом на главную страницу изменён и теперь выводится ровно столько же блоков, сколько и записей. Уже продвижение, но теперь проблема в том, что *Handlebars* не выводит текст.

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const data = await articles.find().exec()
    res.render('index', {data}) 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот оно! Решение моей проблемы!!!

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const data = await articles.find().exec()
    res.render('index', {data}) 
})
```